# Wordpress - How to find users that never logged in?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a Wordpress website with many registered users. Now, I wanna find which users never logged in on the website. On the database, I looked at the table wp_users e wp_usermeta and I didn't find anything useful.

Does Wordpress keep this date information in another place? Can anyone help me?

Comment: maybe a plugin would help https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/when-last-login/#installation

Answer (score 0):

If you install any membership plugin, then you can find the login stats.
You can use "WP-Members Membership Plugin"

Comment: Hi, I'm using Paid Membership Pro, does it have this information?